# Playhaven & Unity: Manager object automatically disables on play

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playhaven

I'm having trouble with playhaven and Unity.

I've added the playhaven plugin, added the game to the playhaven (now Upsight) dashboard online and connected the two. And I've added the Play Haven manager to the scene.

But every time I play the scene, the playhaven manager script component automatically disables itself, so I get 4 errors, the first 2 being about the playhaven secret and token not being specified (I assume because it can't find the manager object because it's disabled).
If I manually turn the component back on, and then move to a scene where there's supposed to be an ad, the default ad pops up, as I assume it should and the errors don't repeat.

My game isn't published, so I'm wondering if that is the issue? Though it seems from the playhaven documentation and website (which admittedly is hard to follow) that this should be possible. Do I have to register a test device and work it on that perhaps?

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the old playhaven unity plugin.

Try downloading the latest Unity 3.0 plugin located here: http://help.analytics.upsight.com/api-sdk-reference/downloads/

The documentation has also been updated to resolve a number of confusing points from the old documentation, located here: http://help.analytics.upsight.com/api-sdk-reference/unity/

If you still run into issues contact support@upsight.com